# How to define jobs on Travis CI on a C++ project

Tags: c++, travis-ci

I'm trying to work with Travis CI on a C++ project but it seems to me that if I set the `language: cpp` attribute, then the jobs are ignored and only `script` is executed.

Here is an example of how my `.travis.yml` file looks like:

```
language: cpp

sudo: required

services:
  - docker

dist: trusty

matrix:
  include:
    - os: linux
      addons:
        apt:
          sources:
            - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
          packages:
            - g++-4.9
      env:
        - MATRIX_EVAL="CC=gcc-4.9 && CXX=g++-4.9"

before_install:
  - eval "${MATRIX_EVAL}"
  - docker pull somedockerimage

jobs:
  include:
    - stage: check
      script:
        - docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/code somedockerimage bash -c 'somecommand /code/*.sh'
    - stage: build
      script:
        - mkdir build
        - cd build
        - cmake ../
        - make
    - stage: test
      script:
        - ./test
```

Travis tries to execute `./configure && make && make test` because there is no `script` section. If I define a `script` section it completely ignores the `jobs` one.

Comment: have you tried including the `os: linux` tag in the base (like above `dist`)?

Comment: Actually not, but I assume that, with `dist: trusty`, specifying linux is redundant... I just copied the matrix part from an official example and that's why it is also there... At the end, I gave up with the matrix and the job is just fine now.